# Не работает проверка символов в cmd

Tags: java

Когда я сравниваю символ введённый с клавиатуры в eclipse то он проверяет нормально, а вот в cmd уже не работает, только русские символы

```
char test = new Scanner(System.in).next().toCharArray()[0];
    if('Д'==test){
        System.out.println("да");
    }
```

Comment: Кодировеу исходника при компиляции правильную указываете?

Comment: а какая должна быть?

Comment: вместо char используй лучше string

Comment: Такая, в которой исходник. Желательно, utf-8.

Comment: cmd по умолчанию работает в 866. Вызови что-нибудь чтобы перейти в более подходящую кодировку.

Comment: попробуйте ввести в командной строке CHCP 65001